# Java: Forcing a String to be a certain length and spaced out

Tags: java, string, substring

```
cardNumber should be an 16 character string e.g. 1111222233334444. 
getCardNumber() should return this as the formatted version 
e.g. 1111 2222 3333 4444.
```

How would I go about making sure that the String is 16 characters long, and then how would I space it out like in the example? Is there a way to use Substring() methods to do this?

Comment: Yes, there is indeed! Have a look at the documentation of substring - if you still have questions after doing that, it's better to ask them directly. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)

Comment: There are no `Substring` but `substring`.

Comment: a 16 character string and you only typed 12 characters. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try regex like this :

```
public static void main(String... strings) {
    String s = "1111222233334444";
    System.out.println(s.matches("\\d{16}")); // check whether string contains exactly 16 digits
    String newString = s.replaceAll("(\\d{4})", "$1"+" ").trim(); // replace every %4th digit by digit+" "
    System.out.println(newString);
}
```

O/P :

```
true
1111 2222 3333 4444
```

Comment: Wouldn't `s.matches("^\\d{16}$")` be better?

Comment: @stuXnet - Nope. By default `matches()` matches the *entire string* from beginning to end. SO it is not necessary.

Comment: Nice answer. Though I would avoid using regex if I were still at the beginning of String processing.

Comment: But this would give you a space at the last.

Comment: @DeiAndrei - There is never a bad time (or should I say *good time*?) to learn regex :P

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex as shown by TheLostMind

Or, more simply:

```
String cardNumber = ...; // input
if (cardNumber.length() == 16) { // input is correct
   return cardNumber.substring(0, 4) + " "
          + cardNumber.substring(4, 8) + " "
          + cardNumber.substring(8, 12) + " "
          + cardNumber.substring(12, 16);
} else {
   // length is incorrect
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [String.length()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length()) to check the length of the number.

Then, let [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) do the formatting job for you:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
df.setGroupingSize(4);
df.setGroupingUsed(true);
DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
dfs.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);

System.out.println(df.format(new BigDecimal("1234567890123456")));
```

If the input contains any non-numeric characters, BigDecimal will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Needlessly complicated version:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String cardNumber = "1111222233334444";
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    if (cardNumber.length() != 16) {
        System.out.println("Wrong length");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < cardNumber.length(); i++) {
            result.append(cardNumber.charAt(i));
            if (i != 0 && (i + 1) % 4 == 0 && i != cardNumber.length() - 1)
                result.append(" ");
        }

        System.out.println(result.toString()); //print result as string or use in method
    }
}
```

}

For real, use regex or substring.

Comment: Hey thanks this is great! I think the formatted String needs to be "returned" though so it can be printed out in another method

Comment: @Patterrz you can just assign it to a variable instead of printing it :) but seriously use the other solutions. edited answer with variable stringbuilder

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below look-around based regex.

```
String s = "1111222233334444";
if(s.matches("\\d{16}"))
{
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?!^)(\\d{4})(?=(?:\\d{4})*$)", " $1"));
}
```

**Output:**

```
1111 2222 3333 4444
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xM5rB7/2)